# Create Javascript template literal with a Popup Modal button

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript template literal which will loop through the objects and display the content. Now I need to display a button for each object and when clicked, it will do a modal pop-up with details of the content.

[image]

However, I am not able to open the popup modal when the button is clicked. Here is my code.

```
var Data = [
    {
        id: "1",
        name: "test1",
        about: "Small Description",
        description: "description",
        photo: "./img/tourism/img.jpg",
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        name: "test2",
        about: "Small Description",
        description: "description",
        photo: "./img/tourism/img.jpg"
    }
```

//Javascript

```
document.getElementById("tourismData").innerHTML = `${Data.map(template).join('')}`
document.getElementById("tourismDesc").innerHTML = `${Data.map(Desc).join('')}`
```

//function for display content

```
template = (place) =>{

    return `
    <div>
        <h4>${place.name}</h4>
        <p>About: ${place.about}</P>
        <button id="btn_${+place.id}" onclick="descOpen(this.id)">More Info</button>        
    </div>
    `
}
```

//description details

```
function Desc(place){
    return `

        <div class="bg-modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="closeButton" id="close">+</div>
                <h4>${place.name}</h4>
                <p>${place.description}</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    `
}

function descOpen(clicked_id){
    document.querySelector('bg-modal').style.display = 'flex'; //seems like this is picking up only the first object.
}
```

My problem is that the modal is picking up only the first object even if I clicked on the second object button

Comment: Uh, your `descOpen` function does not open any modal, it does change the display style of the clicked button itself.

Comment: Thanks. I have slightly changed the descOpen function (updated the description). its now opening  the model, however, its picking up only the first object modal even if we click on any buttons.

Comment: I doubt `document.querySelector('bg-modal')` works, there is no `<bg-modal>` element? If you used `.bg-modal` as the selector, yes, `querySelector` only selects a single element. But you wouldn't want to open *all* modals at once anyway, right? You somehow need to derive from the `clicked_id` *which* modal to select and open.